# How to create tags without creating a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

While browsing the site I noticed that there are no separate tags yet for the new Samsung Galaxy Tabs (8.9 and 10.1) and tried to find a place to create these in order to encourage separation of the old Tab and the new Honeycomb models. Can the tags be created in advance or do we have to wait for someone to create such a question? Furthermore, should new tags be added for all new devices as they are published or when the first question about them is posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We <del>should</del>can only create tags when there are posts to put them against.

For one thing, no one may actually ask a question about that device.

For another, the Stack Exchange software removes tags that don't have any questions associated with them after some number of days. (Four, I think.) So even if we <del>did</del>could set up tags ahead of time it's likely they'd get deleted before someone used them.

Comment: @onik the best way to handle this is to ask an actual question that legitimately requires the tag. That also "proves" the tag has a *reason* to exist...